# Does anyone know where to find the model specification in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have run a logistic regression model is spss.  Where does it store the model specification?

Comment: I don't have logit regression my machine at the moment, but you can frequently save the model in either xml format or in another dataset through the GUI. If you can't do that, you can save any model output (in new datasets) through the OMS system. What exactly do you mean when you say "model specification"?

Comment: Mode specification: what exactly the model is predicting.

Comment: example: x+ exp (Ul)/ Sum(ExpV1)

Comment: I'm still confused, are you asking for the predicted probabilities? Or do you want the model coefficients? I'll be in the chat room if have further clarification (to avoid extended discussion in comments), http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold

Comment: I don't have enough of a reputation to talk in chat room. I want the model coefficients.

Comment: See this example by UCLA, http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/dae/logit.htm , what format do you want the model coefficients? Is just seeing them in the output good enough or do you need them in a dataset?

Answer (score 2):

The model coefficients are displayed in the output pivot tables.  Related settings can be seen in the Notes table.  (This can be saved as xml, html, Excel and various other formats with OUTPUT EXPORT or OMS).

The journal file, if active, records all your syntax as well.

Both the binary and multinomial logistic procedures can save the model to an xml file directly, and various outputs such as predicted categories can be saved as variables in the dataset.

HTH,
Jon Peck